# Why using html file starting with <!DOCTYPE html> served with CherryPy on Windows looks wrong?

Tags: python, css, windows, mime-types, cherrypy

Can anyone explain why using  results in missing css within the browser?
I prepared a small test (look at https://gist.github.com/bmxp/f0f4ebe52019d2d239ab0abe8f5e4867) where the only distinction between two html files served is the first line.

## On Windows platform:

So if  is omitted (as in index.html) then the background looks fine in green and we have a pleasing **Hello world**

If  is included then css won't be used for display.

If the first line is changed to have html misspelled like  then the document displays fine. But as soon as html or HTmL or other variations are together in the first line it fails to use css.

## On Linux platform:

Either file displays fine.

So I suspect the cause to be with windows or with cherrypy implementation on windows.

The error shows with any browser I tried: Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Opera

Comment: PS: I found two other computers with windows which do it right

Comment: Using other version of python3 or CherryPy does not change the results

Answer (score 2):

Finally it turned out to be a combination of two problems:

## First

If starting a document with only `<html> ...` then this seems to be considered to be not really a valid html file.
Thus an enclosed link to a css which is delivered with `text/plain` as mimetype will display fine.

If starting correctly with `<!DOCTYPE html> ...` then it is not forgiven that the mimetype  is essentially wrong.

## Second

CherryPy delivered `text/plain` as mimetype for my css file. I tried it on two other windows computers and it did not show the problem. I tried another older computer which I used earlier for some development and it showed the same buggy behaviour...

Linux never showed this failure not with any flavour I tried out.

I investigated deeper: Cherrypy uses the python standard mimetype module or I can pass a dedicated Content-Type for css when including `'tools.staticdir.content_types': { 'css': 'text/css' }` in my `\static` config. When passing the dedicated Content-Type the failure was gone.

Now why seems there always to be a wrong association on just certain windows systems?
I found out that winreg is used to directly read mimetypes out of the registry.
Inspecting `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.css` showed an association with `text\plain`.
So this caused my headaches!
After changing `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.css[Content Type]` to `text/css` it finally worked as expected. The last association at my development computer within the registry was (Standard) with `VisualStudio.css.14.0`, it might thus be that the mimetype was set by this program as well.

The issue was discussed on gitter.im at cherrypy/cherrypy and I got help there with ideas and suggestions so a big thank you @webknjaz and @cyraxjoe for trying to help me